# How Stack or memory is allocated for threads under the same process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory, process, stack

For a normal function call, stack frame is created and stored in stack. But
How memory is allocated for two thread within one process and how stack frame is handled when thread call other function.

Comment: Not a bad question, but you can get answer by Google search.

Comment: @pranit Kothari I tried but dint get satisfactory answer.Like if we create one thread, how main thread and new tread share same stack or they use two different stack ..etc

Comment: Each thread has its own stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current 'thread' concept in Linux is the [NPTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) one. NPTL uses [`clone()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), which wraps [`sys_clone()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sys_clone). Allocating a stack for a new 'thread' is handled in the user space (ie. libc), not in kernel (ie. Linux). A library can allocate a stack using the allocation of choice (eg. malloc) and then call clone() passing this address as the stack (of course, needs to pass the *top* of the allocated region, since stacks grow downwards on most platforms):

> Unlike fork(2), clone() allows the child process to share parts of its execution context with the calling process, such as the memory space, the table of file descriptors, and the table of signal handlers. ...
>
> The main use of clone() is to implement threads: multiple threads of control in a program that run concurrently in a shared memory space.
>
> When the child process is created with clone(), it executes the function fn(arg) ...
>
> The child_stack argument specifies the location of the stack used by the child process ...

If you want to learn more specific details, open the source of your distro [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) implementation and get reading.

For example [`pthread_create.c`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/nptl/pthread_create.c):

```
int
__pthread_create_2_1 (newthread, attr, start_routine, arg)
  ...
  struct pthread *pd = NULL;
  int err = ALLOCATE_STACK (iattr, &pd);
  ...
```

and [allocatestack.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/nptl/allocatestack.c):

```
 # define ALLOCATE_STACK(attr, pd) allocate_stack (attr, pd, &stackaddr)

 static int
 allocate_stack (const struct pthread_attr *attr, struct pthread **pdp,
    ALLOCATE_STACK_PARMS)
 ...
```

You'll see that stack allocation has some whistles and bells, like caching and reusing stack regions, [guard pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setguardsize.3.html), but in the end is just a memory region allocated in user space.

Comment: Ok, was not able to edit this answer anyway, Its NPTL and not NTPL.

Answer (score 1):

As someone commented each thread have it's own stack. When function gets called from that thread new stack frame is created in that stack.